# Attempt to call an undefined function glutInit

Tags: python, python-3.x, glut, pyopengl

I need a glut window in python.
I have the following exception using Python 3.5 and PyOpenGL.GLUT

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\...\Test.py", line 47, in <module>

    if __name__ == '__main__': main()
  File "D:\...\Test.py", line 9, in main
    glutInit(sys.argv)
  File "C:\...\OpenGL\GLUT\special.py", line 333, in glutInit
    _base_glutInit( ctypes.byref(count), holder )
  File "C:\...\OpenGL\platform\baseplatform.py", line 407, in __call__
    self.__name__, self.__name__,

OpenGL.error.NullFunctionError: Attempt to call an undefined function glutInit,
check for bool(glutInit) before calling
```

Platform: **Windows**

Why do i get this error?

Here is my code:

```
from OpenGL.GLUT import *
import sys

glutInit(sys.argv)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26700719/pyopengl-glutinit-nullfunctionerror

Comment: that question has no answer marked as solution, and the real problem is that the module is not properly reporting missing dll files

Comment: and that question is about anaconda and python 2.7

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**Problems:**

- There was no problem with `pip install` or `easy_install`
- The `glut.dll` and `glut32.dll` were missing. (They are not part of the PyPI package) you have to install them separately or [download](http://freeglut.sourceforge.net/index.php#download) it like I did.

Unzipped the `dll` files from the `glutdlls.zip` and placed them next to my python file.

**Note:** You can add the `dll` files to your `PATH` variable. Not necessary to keep them next to the `py` file.

Comment: Worked for me.Some clarification for future readers of this: The link to the two needed dlls is: [link](ftp://ftp.sgi.com/opengl/glut/glutdlls.zip) On Windows 7 put `glut.dll` and `glut32.dll` in your Python2.7 OpenGL DLL folder.

Comment: The FTP link is no longer hosted.

Comment: The FTP link is no longer hosted.

Comment: Uninstall your current PyOpenGL and simply download PyOpenGL from [Unofficial Windows Python Binaries](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pyopengl) and then install the whl using pip.

Comment: As @KareemElashmawy indicated, the link of @JayJay is not available anymore.
From: https://www.transmissionzero.co.uk/files/software/development/GLUT/freeglut-MSVC.zip
one can copy the `/freeglut-MSVC-3.0.0-2.mp\freeglut\bin\x64/freeglut.dll` file into the folder of the `.py` script you are trying to run. This resolves the error from `OpenGL.error.NullFunctionError: Attempt to call an undefined function glutInit` to: `ctypes.ArgumentError:  wrong type` at `OpenGL\GLUT\special.py", line 73, in glutCreateWindow`. Perhaps cause I only found 1/2 .dll files.

Comment: The 2nd error was for installing "official" PyOpenGL with: `conda install -c conda-forge pyopengl` which didnt work. Solution I uninstalled the official version with `pip uninstall PyOpenGL` and installed the Unofficial Windows Binaries as @MAY suggested. That initially threw errors: `.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.` for both the 32 and 64 bit version, but that was because I forgot to select the `python 36 version` with the name `PyOpenGL‑3.1.5‑cp<PYTHON VERSION>‑cp<PYTHON VERSION>m‑win_amd64.whl`. Hope this helps someone. Also installed `conda install -c conda-forge freeglut`.

Comment: Had to deal with this recently, @MAY's recommendation is what worked for me.
installing freeglut from conda-forge was not required in my case, maybe because I already had it somewhere else (vcpkg?)

Comment: I had to name the glut dll as "site-packages/OpenGL/DLLS/freeglut64.vc9.dll" before it was found. Finding the dll is the job of "OpenGL/platform/ctypesloader.py" and I had to breakpoint inside that file to find out what file name it was seeking. (Am using python 2.7)

Answer (score 1):

I was being thrown the same error message. I tried installing the DLLs separately and everything and nothing worked.
The code that gave me the error was calling the glutInit() function. While I was getting the error, my imports looked like:

```
import OpenGL
import OpenGL.GL
import OpenGL.GLUT
import OpenGL.GLU
```

I then changed my imports to:

```
import OpenGL
from OpenGL.GL import *
from OpenGL.GLUT import *
from OpenGL.GLU import *
```

and the error was fixed.

Answer (score 0):

I tried some other thing and it worked perfectly. the path Lib/site-packages/OpenGL/GL/DLLS MUST have the dll file. No other thing required. No cmake or Visual C++ as may some sites suggest.