# How to install GLUT on Anaconda on Windows?

Tags: windows, python-3.x, opengl, anaconda, glut

I'm trying to run a simple OpenGL code:

```
from OpenGL.GL import *
from OpenGL.GLUT import *
from OpenGL.GLU import *

window = 0                                             # glut window number
width, height = 500, 400                               # window size

def draw():                                            # ondraw is called all the time
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT) # clear the screen
    glLoadIdentity()                                   # reset position

    # ToDo draw rectangle

    glutSwapBuffers()                                  # important for double buffering


# initialization
glutInit()                                             # initialize glut
glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_RGBA | GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_ALPHA | GLUT_DEPTH)
glutInitWindowSize(width, height)                      # set window size
glutInitWindowPosition(0, 0)                           # set window position
window = glutCreateWindow("noobtuts.com")              # create window with title
glutDisplayFunc(draw)                                  # set draw function callback
glutIdleFunc(draw)                                     # draw all the time
glutMainLoop()
```

But everytime I try to execute it I get this error:

```
OpenGL.error.NullFunctionError: Attempt to call an undefined function glutInit,
check for bool(glutInit) before calling
```

According to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39181192/attempt-to-call-an-undefined-function-glutinit) The problem is that the `glut.dll` and `glut32.dll` are not part of the `PyOpenGL` package. So I downloaded the dll files and copied them to `C:/Windows/SysWOW64` and added that folder to `PATH`, but the error persists. In the same question reference above, one user also suggests coping the dll files to the `Python OpenGL DLL` folder.

Where can I find this folder in my Ananconda installation? Or where should I copy the dll files to make this work? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rabbid76's response solved the problem:

"When I installed OpenGL on my Windows system, I follow [this](https://codeyarns.com/2012/04/27/pyopengl-installation-notes-for-windows/) instructions and downloaded the binaries (.whl) from [here](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pyopengl)"