# pyopengl: undefined function gluPerspective, check for bool(gluPerspective) before calling

Tags: python, opengl, fedora, pyopengl

I am currently writting tests for the `toggle_fullscreen`-Function in Pygame, because I am [working together with others on the Pygame-Documentation](https://github.com/pygame/pygame/issues/1990) for `toggle_fullscreen` because of the coming 2.0 release of Pygame.

I am writing tests for Fedora-Linux (because it uses Wayland). The first test with a 'normal' window was easy, but now I am having trouble with the 'OpenGL' variant.

I am not very experienced with OpenGL, so I used an example code I found and wanted to modify it then to my needs. I get the following error, when I try to run the code found [here](https://pythonprogramming.net/opengl-rotating-cube-example-pyopengl-tutorial/):

```
OpenGL.error.NullFunctionError: Attempt to call an undefined function gluPerspective, check for bool(gluPerspective) before calling
```

Because I am not on Windows, I can't use the [unofficial Windows-Binaries](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/). Secondly, I am not able to add the maybe necessary dlls (still because it's not Windows) as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39181192/attempt-to-call-an-undefined-function-glutinit).

I also tried `pygame.example.glcube`, but it did not help, same error. On Windows, I am not having this Problem with the same code.

Fedora 32:

- Python 3.8.5, Pygame 1.9.6, pyopengl 3.1.5

Windows 10:

- Python 3.8.1, Pygame 1.9.6, pyopengl 3.1.5