# Glut methods not recognised even with dll's(Pyopengl3/Python3.8/Windows10-64)

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, pyopengl, pyc

On running the main script in Pyopengl3.1.5(Python3.8- Windows10Pro/64bit) **installed via Pip**,the compiler doesn't recognise Glut methods.

After following these stackoverflow answers ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26700719/pyopengl-glutinit-nullfunctionerror#answer-40354664) & [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39181192/attempt-to-call-an-undefined-function-glutinit/39181193#39181193)) ie.reinstalling [Pyopengl wheel](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pyopengl) & putting [dll's](https://www.transmissionzero.co.uk/software/freeglut-devel#content) in main script folder(**C:..Python\…\site-packages** - PyOpengl's main directory) ,Environment Path,System32 & SysWow64 , the compiler still gives the same error :

```
import OpenGL.GLUT  
glutInit()
NameError: name 'glutInit' is not defined (# checked for casetype )
```

However, there is a python script named "special.py" located in Site-packages\Opengl\Glut which has the glut methods defined.So on adding the glutinit method's path to *init*.py (Glut directory)and compiling, the compiler still gives following errors.

```
OpenGL\GLUT\special.py:- def glutInit(INITIALIZED = False)   

OpenGL\GLUT\init.py:- from OpenGL.GLUT.special import *
                      from OpenGL.GLUT.special import glutInit (#added)  


OpenGL\GLUT\main.py:- import OpenGL.GLUT
                      import OpenGL.GLUT.special(#added) 
                      import OpenGL.GLUT.special.glutInit (#added)   

                      glutInit(INITIALIZED = True)  (# function call)

                      ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'OpenGL.GLUT.special.glutInit'; 'OpenGL.GLUT.special' is not a package
```

So the question is - How to get the ***compiler to recognise the glut methods in special.py*** and also is there ***any way to update the .pyc files*** so as to reflect the updated init.py import path's?

Main Pyopengl Script  (stackabuse.com)

```
import OpenGL
import OpenGL.GL
import OpenGL.GLUT
import OpenGL.GLUT.special #(added)
import OpenGL.GLUT.special.glutInit #(added)
import OpenGL.GLU
print("Imports successful!")

w, h = 500,500

# define square 
def square():
    # We have to declare the points in this sequence: bottom left, bottom right, top right, top left
glBegin(GL_QUADS) # Begin the sketch
glVertex2f(100, 100) # Coordinates for the bottom left point
glVertex2f(200, 100) # Coordinates for the bottom right point
glVertex2f(200, 200) # Coordinates for the top right point
glVertex2f(100, 200) # Coordinates for the top left point
glEnd() # Mark the end of drawing


# draw square
def showScreen():
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT) # Remove everything from screen (i.e. displays all white)
    glLoadIdentity() # Reset all graphic/shape's position
    square() # Draw a square using our function
    glutSwapBuffers()

# Initialise and create Opengl screen
glutInit(True)
glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_RGBA) # Set the display mode to be colored
glutInitWindowSize(500, 500)   # Set the w and h of your window
glutInitWindowPosition(0, 0)   # Set the position at which this windows should appear
wind = glutCreateWindow("OpenGL Coding Practice") # Set a window title
glutDisplayFunc(showScreen)
glutIdleFunc(showScreen) # Keeps the window open
glutMainLoop()  # Keeps the above created window displaying/running in a loop
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either you have to precede the module path to at each function call:

For instance:

<s>`glutInit(True)`</s>

```py
OpenGL.GLUT.glutInit()
```

Or you have to change the [`import`  statements](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#import), by using the  `from` clause.

For instance:

```py
from OpenGL import *
from OpenGL.GL import *
from OpenGL.GLUT import *
from OpenGL.GLU import *
```

Comment: Importing everything  with import * worked ...still not sure why the other two options provided in my code didn't work.  refer:-https://docs.python-guide.org/writing/structure/#modules   .Also adding brackets() to functions (SyntaxError)is not required while importing

Comment: @starzar *"Also adding brackets() to functions [...] while importing"* - Where are there brackets in the import statement? The first line of code in my answer is a function call not an import!

Comment: Yeah ,it is a function call not an import . But this leads to preceding every function with the directory path  totally nullify's the use of Import. eg OpenGL.GLUT.special.glutInit(),OpenGL.GLUT.special.glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_RGBA) .....etc

Comment: @starzar Yes, I know. That is what I've tried to say in my answer. Either precede the module paths to each function call or change the import.